Google Play Store says "your device isn't compatible with this version"
I upgraded my app from Android 13 to 14 (i.e. API level 34). I was able to deploy the app and run it just fine locally.
After I deployed to the Google Play Store, the store now says "your device isn't compatible with this version".
To confirm the version, the Google Play Console says this release is indeed "Target SDK 34" and "API levels 29+".
This may not be relevant, but I'm still confusingly getting a policy error on the Google Play Console, saying I need to upgrade to Android 14 by August 30th.
here's the manifest. It hasn't changed.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.unity3d.player"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature android:name="oculus.software.overlay_keyboard" android:required="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.oculus.permission.USE_SCENE"/>
    <application>
        <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity"
                  android:theme="@style/UnityThemeSelector">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>


EDIT SOLVED:
I figured it out, just had to remove the Oculus permissions/features from the manifest. The Android 14 upgrade was a red herring.

Show us the actual violation message in console (screenshot) , also screenshot the release overview. And olanother thing, are you an internal tester

I figured it out. I have to remove the Oculus permissions/features from the manifest, since those aren't supported on Android mobile devices.
